# FileNotFound on url.openStream()

Tags: java, sockets, url

I am writing a Client application which sends requests to the server. I have started my server from Windows, using StartServer batch file. Now, the requests that server expects are HTTP requests. If I open up a request from my web browser, the server sees it and responds to it, but I am having a bad time trying to send the requests from Java.

For example, command `"http://localhost/?command=reg&person=sophie"` works fine when started from a browser, but from Java it returns a FileNotFound exception.

Here is the code:

```
public class Client {

private Socket clientSocket;
private final int PORT_NUMBER;
private final String HOST_NAME;

private PrintWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;

public Client(int PORT_NUMBER, String HOST_NAME){
    this.PORT_NUMBER = PORT_NUMBER;
    this.HOST_NAME = HOST_NAME;


    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER);
        writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error creating socket!");
    }
}


public void registerPerson(String personName) throws IOException{

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/?command=reg&person=sophie");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
    sc.nextLine();

}
```

This line, `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());`, returns a FileNotFound exception. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: How did you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. The problem might arise because java does not recognize your loopback address (ie `localhost`).

Comment: Yes, it's all the same with 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the URL differently?

```
      URL fileURL = new URL("http://localhost/?command=reg&person=sophie");
      URLConnection connection = fileURL.openConnection();
      connection.connect();
      inputStream = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Also using the IP address instead of localhost is a good idea, as suggested in an another answer.

Comment: Still the same problem, Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://127.0.0.1/?command=reg&person=sophie

Comment: Perhaps adding the port number to the URL will help

Comment: Adding port didnt help, it's well known gate 80, anyway.